# Why is the 'click' event not fired when the shift key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, click, dom-events, shift

I'm trying to understand how the events are implemented in leaflet, and I have difficulties understanding how it works.

[Here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth-example.html) is a map made with leaflet (comes form a standard tutorial on the leaflet site). If you click on a state, it zooms to it. Unless you press shift, and only shift.

Here is the associated code:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
     layer.on({
         mouseover: highlightFeature,
         mouseout: resetHighlight,
         click: zoomToFeature
     });
}
```

Nowhere in the code can I find a reference to shift. Any idea of what happens?

Comment: looking for "shift" in the minimized code, looks like it is detected. The plugin does it.

Comment: You're absolutely right, just found it in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's leaflet [boxzoom](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-class) options that will cause the behavior.

The [code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/54b2887667f689fa12ed1ef5fd6971f3ee8a0c58/src/map/handler/Map.BoxZoom.js) responsable for it is in Leaflet

> / src / map / handler / Map.BoxZoom.js

file:

```
    _onMouseDown: function (e) {
    if (!e.shiftKey || ((e.which !== 1) && (e.button !== 1))) { return false; }
```